# how to solve your php server doesn't have mysql module loaded

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver, host, vesta

i am trying to connect my hosting php server to dreamweaver application but it says  "solve your php server doesn't have mysql module loaded".
can some body help me to fix this ..
Or explain step by step how to make connection

Comment: um install mysql?  .. how is this hosted?

Comment: useing xamp in pc

Comment: hosted by vestacp

Comment: which version of php you are using can you specify?

Comment: useing php 5.6.33 on vestacp server

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution be among below :

1. Install Mysql server.
2. uncomment out `connection = php_mysql` in **php.ini** file.
3. If you using IIS try again with Apache. as php not works well with IIS
4. use MySQLi Server Behaviors an Dreamweaver extension which is improved, streamlined version of MySQL.

Comment: "uncomment out connection = php_mysql in php.ini file." 
should i uncomment both in server and pc

Comment: did not found connection=php_myql in php.ini

Comment: try with **extension=php_mysql.dll**

Comment: Should i do same in server and Pc

Comment: extension=msql.dll found this
did not found extension=php_mysql.dll

Answer (score 0):

Your XAMPP control panel should have a mySQL (or mariaDB) button[image]

All you have to do is press the `Start` button, and then wait until the indicator turns green. If you do not have this button, you did not install mySQL (or mariaDB on newer versions), and this requires a modification of XAMPP installation, or even a full reinstall.

Comment: ya i installed this running well but when connect mysql php admin database in  Dreamweaver it says error

Answer (score 0):

Which PHP version do you have on your remote and local testing servers?  If unsure, add this code to a new PHP test page and run it from your server & localhost.

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Deprecated server behaviors in DW are outdated and no longer supported in PHP 7+, you can try with PHP 5 > latest version, that should solve it, we get used to not respecting PHP versions of our editors like DW, and the issues of communication failure start there.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcMts.png)

I experienced the same thing,
Database >> MySQL Connection >> after filling out the form for connecting dreamweaver to xampp >> Your PHP server doesn't have the mysql_(p)connect function.

i don't know the error on xampp or dreamweaver i use.

DW 2014 to DW 2021 all failed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).